# Python Pandas : Lowest/Highest value since a certain row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set (pd.DataFrame) which looks somewhat like this:

```
date    0
2015 Q4 -1.0
2016 Q1 0.8
2016 Q2 0
2016 Q3 0.1
2016 Q4 0.7
2017 Q1 -0.4
2017 Q2 -0.2
2017 Q3 1.2
2017 Q4 0.8
2018 Q1 -0.4
```

I am trying to find the last time the data in my column was as low as the latest row (in this case: it would have been in 2017 Q1), and would need it to work so that if the latest number was positive it would find the last time it was as high.

After having found that, I would need to extract the index value of that row. ('2017 Q1' in this case)

I've been trying what feels like an abomination of code (I only recently started coding):

```
from heapq import nsmallest
from heapq import nlargest
    def second_smallest(numbers):
        return nsmallest(2, numbers)[-1]
    def second_largest(numbers):
        return nlargest(2, numbers)[-1]


    def next_smallest(df = pd.DataFrame()):
        x = df[-1:].item()
        if x <= 0:
            y = df[df>= x]
            second = second_smallest(y)
            return  df.index[df == second].tolist()
```

which does not give me the required result, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Been looking around for a while and either my wording is wrong when searching (second language so it happens sometimes), or there isn't much on how to do that.

Many thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure I get the problem correct, you said: "I am trying to find the last time the data in my column was as low as the latest row (in this case: it would have been in 2015 Q4)". In this example, wouldn't it be 2017 Q1? The latest row is 2018 Q1 with a value of -0.4, and 2017 Q1 has the value -0.4 which is later than 2015 Q4.

Comment: Ah yes you are right. My latest point used to be -0.5 in which case it made sense but you are correct. Will edit thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this give you what you are looking for?

```
if df.value.iloc[-1] < 0: 
    idx = df.index[df.value<=df.value.iloc[-1]][-2]
else:
    idx = df.index[df.value>=df.value.iloc[-1]][-2]

date = df.date.iloc[idx]
```

Comment: I get "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value' ". Should have specified it was a df maybe ? Added it in my post.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I renamed your '0' column to 'value' with `df.columns = ['date','value']`.

Comment: Oh right that makes sense. And yea when using the name I have for it this works perfectly. Much easier than the weird ways I was going about it I have to say, many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Labeling your first column as 'id' and second column as 'value', one approach could be to identify all rows with the same value as the latest row, and then get the last date that had this value. See below with mock up data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['date1', 'date2', 'date3', 'date4', 'date5', 'date6', 'date7', 'date8'], 'value': [3, -1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3]})
df_same_value_as_latest = df.loc[df['value']==df['value'].tolist()[-1]]
date_required = df_same_value_as_latest.iloc[df_same_value_as_latest.shape[0]-2,:]['id']
print(date_required)
```

Comment: My dataset has more decimals than what I pasted (for clarity) so I believe this would cause problems ? + The potential of there not being 2 equal values would also break it I think.

Comment: In your question you did say 'equal'... I suppose you can apply rounding to your data but that's probably not desirable, alternatively my answer can be modified to work with greater than or less than conditions, although that would become pretty much the same as the accepted answer

Comment: Yes sorry if I wasn't clear, equal is fine but there is a possibility there won't be any equal points in which case I would need the closest one i.e.: If the next time a row is appended the value is -0.6. But thank you for your answer !

Comment: You are most welcome :) Sure I guess in that case technically the answer is the date of the latest row itself - guess it depends on what you are trying to achieve!